# If $(X,d)$ is compact (why?) and $(E,d')$ is complete then $\mathscr{C}(X,E)$ is complete (equipped with the topology of unif. convergence).

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

A theorem in a book that I am looking into states that if $(X,d)$ is compact and $(E,d')$ is complete then $\mathscr{C}(X,E)$ is complete (equipped with the metric $d_u$ of uniform convergence).

Now the thing is that I do not see why the compactness on $(X,d)$ is necessary. Is it maybe so that $d_u(f,g)$ would be finite for $f, g \in \mathscr{C}(X,E)$?

Can we "overcome" this problem if we replace $d'$ by $d''= \frac{d'}{1+ d'}$ as a metric on $E$?

Comment: You are right, compactness is not necessary other than to make the natural metric "well-defined". What is essential is completeness of $E$. If you work on a bounded metric, then you can circumvent the issue of a $\infty$ distance. Note, for instance, that $\mathcal{F}(X,E)$ (space of functions) is a complete space if $E$ is complete. $\mathcal{C}(X,E)$ being a closed subspace of the former implies it is complete as well.

Answer (score -1):

> The condition that $X$ is compact is essential, because:

Every continuous function on a compact set is bounded.  The uniform  metric is given by $d(f,g)=\sup_{x\in X}|f(x)-g(x)|$.  Since the function is bounded the set $\{f(x):x\in X\}$ is bounded and so its supremum exits.

Comment: Down vote: See my previous comment

Comment: My first comment seems to be lost.@ Aloizio Macedo and @learnmore don't agree with each other.